# Why does Visual Studio Code seem to ignore my includePath?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, bind

I cloned the Bind9 repository from https://github.com/isc-projects/bind9 to better understand the codebase for `named`.

I loaded the project into Visual Studio Code and configured my `c_cpp_properties.json` as follows:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            ],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

However, when trying to debug/execute the `bind9/bin/named/main.c` file, I still get a `No such file or directory` error on the includes.

[image: error]

I confirmed that the header files are in the workspace folder.
My guess is that Visual Studio Code might know about them, but that GCC is struggling to get the correct includes. But, I do not know how to solve that issue.

Comment: You confuse the settings for your editor (or the "C/C++ extension pack") with the settings of your compiler. The include path for the compiler must be configured in `tasks.json` of your workspace

Comment: I included the `"-I${workspaceFolder}/**"` argument in the `tasks,json`, but unfortunately the problem still persists.

Comment: I don't think, the compiler will understand `.../**` You need to specify each path separately.